# Problem of calling SOAP webservice from sharepoint designer 2013 workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, designer-workflow, soap

Have any one called SOAP web service from SharePoint designer 2013 workflow? or faced problem for calling SOAP web service from SharePoint designer 2013 workflow? What problem generally arise in this case? Please share your experience. Should we avoid calling SOAP web service from SharePoint designer 2013 workflow?

My requirement is to call SOAP web service in a particular interval in on-prem 2013 application should we use SharePoint designer 2013 workflow or Visual studio workflow? what is the correct way?
e.g.  SAP is generating SOAP web web service. how to call those from SharePoint 2013 designer workflow?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to call a SOAP web service from SharePoint designer workflow. Though you can still call the web service in a page by adding the datasource and show it using a dataview. But I don't think that is what you want.

That said, there is a way you can call SOAP web services from workflow. Nintex workflow allows you to do that.

**Disclaimer:** I'm not advertising Nintex and do not work for Nintex.

Anyway, when you want to call a SOAP web service at a specific interval, why not use a timer job to do that?